# Why is it insufficient funds when sending coins via datacoind when I have enough?

Tags: datacoin

I'm trying to send my coins from my daemon I installed in my server. Its datacoind, but I'm guessing its the same as bitcoind. Is that a correct assumption?

http://prntscr.com/2h4eex

```
root@x:~# datacoind listaccounts
{
    "" : 11.43010363,
    "pat" : 0.00000000,
    "pats" : -0.45000000
}
root@x:~# datacoind sendtoaddress DJKrNvrnuuTsvuwThYfjP2Mo 7 "testing this out"
error: {"code":-4,"message":"Insufficient funds"}
root@x:~#
```

Comment: Off-topic because it's specific to a non-Bitcoin altcoin. Bitcoin won't behave like that.

Comment: I disagree, it is the only stackexchange for cryptocurrency that has any people with extensive knowledge

*EDIT* What is your transaction fee set at

Comment: Crypto currencies other than Bitcoin are still on topic here. See the help center. However, it might help if you can provide some more info about datacoin, for those who may be less familiar.

Comment: if you want to read up on datacoin: www.datacoin.info --- its a new coin that came out about a month ago where you can attach upto 128KB worth of data to each transaction. thereby creating a decentralized cloud storage. a potential game changer i must say.